# Modify 'Read more' link adding a new class

Tags: posts, excerpt, the-content, read-more

I want to add a class to the 'Read more' link. Actually I have this:

```
<?php the_content( 'Read more...' ); ?>
```

Which outputs:

```
<a href="...?p=14#more-14" class="more-link">Read more…</a>
```

How can I add a class (using PHP) to the link, so it outputs:

```
<a href="...?p=14#more-14" class="more-link my_new_class">Read more…</a>
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this globally or just on a single template file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### What (exactly) happens

When calling `the_content()` inside your template, you are able to call it without any parameters. This means, that the function already has the defaults of `null` for both arguments: The "more" link text and the boolean switch that allows you to strip teaser content before the "more" link text.

The `the_content()` function calls `get_the_content()` internally (and passes the arguments in). It then runs all callback functions that are attached to the `the_content`-filter. So basically *nothing* that is related to the link or anything else (aside from the filter) happens inside `the_content()` - it happens inside [`get_the_content()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_the_content/).

And there we got the `the_content_more_link`-filter.

### The filter in core

```
apply_filters( 
    'the_content_more_link',
    ' <a href="' . get_permalink() . "#more-{$post->ID}\" class=\"more-link\">$more_link_text</a>",
    $more_link_text
);
```

### Filters in action

The two arguments after the filter name (1<sup>st</sup> arg), are the accessible arguments inside attached callback functions.

```
// Example: Somewhere in core, a plugin or a theme
$output = apply_filters( 'some_filter', $arg_one, $arg_two );

// Example: Somewhere in a custom plugin
// Attach the filter: Attach filter name, callback function name, priority, number of taken args
add_filter( 'some_filter', 'wpse63748_callback_function', 10, 2 );
function wpse63748_callback_function( $arg_one, $arg_two )
{
    // Do something with Arg One = modify the output
    // You have Arg two to help you

    // Always return the first arg for filter callback functions.
    return $arg_one;
}
```

### Modify the »more«-link

Now the actual/real-life plugin:

```
/** Plugin Name: (#63748) Modify the »more«-link. */
add_action( 'the_content_more_link', 'wpse63748_add_morelink_class', 10, 2 );
function wpse63748_add_morelink_class( $link, $text )
{
    return str_replace(
        'more-link',
        'more-link CUSTOM_CLASSES_HERE',
        $link
    );
}
```

Simply add your classes where you read `CUSTOM_CLASSES_HERE` and then upload it to your plugins directory or remove the comment `Plugin Name: ...` and use it in your themes functions.php file.

Answer (score 1):

You can completely replace the more link using the the_content_more_link filter, just add your class in there, see "custom-class" in the code below:

```
function new_content_more($more) {
       global $post;
       return ' <a href="' . get_permalink() . "#more-{$post->ID}\" class=\"more-link custom-class\">Read More...</a>";
}   
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'new_content_more' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also just add a filter to the original "more..." link, just add this code to your function.php file :

```
function yourtheme_content_more() {
   $link = get_permalink('');
   $new_link = '<span class="see_more"><a class="button" href="' . esc_url($link) . '">See more from this...</a></span>';

   return $new_link;
}
add_filter('the_content_more_link', 'yourtheme_content_more');
```

Answer (score -1):

Wordpress has a explenation in the codex regarding the read more...

You can find it here:

**In a nutshell you can to this:**

```
<?php the_content('<span class="moretext">...on the edge of
your seat? Click here to solve the mystery.</span>'); ?>
```

.
There you can change the class or wrap with a div etc...

Comment: But this doesn't solve my problem as anything I introduce in there will appear inside the link. In your example it will display: <a href="...?p=14#more-14" class="more-link"><span class="moretext">...on the edge of
your seat? Click here to solve the mystery.</span></a>

Comment: sorry - i guess i dont understand... what's the difference...  using this method u can refrence it in your css easily...

Comment: I want to modify the containing link